# Execute bash commands from vim with name of current file name and path to file

Tags: vim

I'm trying to do this to save a file without changing the timestamp.

`nnoremap <F3> :execute 'silent !file=%:p:h && mtime=$(stat -c %y "%") && vim "%" && touch -d "$mtime" "%" && ~/bin/refresh_safari quick'<CR><CR>`

The `%:ph:h` and `%` special variables aren't interpolated, however. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why should it, it is a string. What you want is to combine/concat your string with some variables:

```
'silent !file=' . expand('%:p:h') . ' && mtime ..........
```